# Strange Java calendar inconsistency

Tags: java, calendar

Why such inconsistency?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println("KO current month: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println("OK current month: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
}
```

Output:

```
KO current month: 2
OK current month: 1
```

Comment: Yes, it’s very confusing. The good solution is to drop the confusing `Calendar`class and use `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. I have reproduced, I get the same output as you.

Comment: Thanks. i started using LocalDate and thanksfully the API is accessible for the common developer. Hopefully the switch won't be difficult for other developers. Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Today is 31st May. The `Calendar` object is by default [lenient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient(boolean)) so after the first `set()` the date is switched to 31st February which doesn't exist. `Calendar` leniently fixes it by moving to 3rd March. Month `2` means March.

The second `set()` operation is applied to 3rd March so it switches to 3rd Feb as one would expect. Month `1` means February.

You can see this by formatting the full date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

which returns

```
03/03/18 10:40
03/02/18 10:40
```

If you want to prevent the behaviour you need to call [`setLenient()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient(boolean)) method

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setLenient(false);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

which will results in the following `IllegalArgumentException` exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH: 1 -> 2
>       at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2829)
>       at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
>       ...

Comment: Thanks, you rock! Can't believe i have been bet by this, today !

Answer (score 3):

[Karol Dowbecki’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621163/5772882) is correct and well explained (and I should say well spotted). I should like to provide the good and modern fix.

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.MAY, 31);
    date = date.with(Month.FEBRUARY);
    System.out.println(date.getMonth());
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

```
FEBRUARY
2018-02-28
```

The `Calendar` class is confusing and poorly designed, so instead I am using `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. This API is so much nicer to work with. `LocalDate` will not give you February 31, fortunately, since this date does not exist. It gives you the last day of February and thus the month you had expected.

PS The following initialization would mimic your code:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))`
```

However, I preferred to give code that will also demonstrate the point when someone tries to run it some day in the future.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.